# Any word followed by "proof" means that something is protected against that word

Tags: suffixes, prefixes

I was wondering if you combine any word and add "proof" at the and, does that automatically means that it is protected against the first word?

For example:
Bulletproof - means something that can't be pierced by a bullet

But if I say:
Catproof or Appleproof does that mean something that is protected against cats or apples?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, but consider using a hyphen to coin new compounds, such as "cat-proof." I'm not sure if appleproof would work, since it's not clear what you're proofing yourself against.

Comment: @SEL you are not necessarily proofing *yourself* against cats or apples... But, anyway, I agree that apple-proof is rather hard to get hold of. Oh, I just thought of 'teacher.'

Comment: Those of us who live with cats know that there is no such thing as "cat-proof".

Comment: 'The point of productivity is **not** that you can add a suffix to any word you please, but that it can be added to some words to create new words. [Only if it cannot be added to any words in order to create new words is it said to be unproductive.]' [Cerberus; tweaked] Thus _knife-proof_ has been used and should cause few concerns; but _fork-proof_,  _poniard-proof_, _epee-proof_ and _halberd-proof_ seem extremely rare; _glaves-proof_ vanishingly so. [Wikipedia](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_words_suffixed_with_-proof) lists some (unhyphenated) words with the  suffix _proof_.

Comment: Then again, there is of course the Apple-Haken-proof of the four-colour-theorem, which does not denote that the theorem is protected against apples (or hakens). :)

Comment: You can't get away with that here because this site is neologism-proof!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this is the normal way that compound words are formed. The second meaning of *proof* as [defined](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proof) by the online Merriam-Webster is

> designed or made to prevent or protect against something harmful

So, yes, if you were to coin *appleproof* it would indeed be understood as something that is safe from apples. The only exception I know of is are numbers. Because of another meaning of the word *proof*, *hundredproof* would not mean "safe from hundreds" but 50% alcohol. From the same source:

> b :  strength with reference to the standard for proof spirit; specifically :  alcoholic strength indicated by a number that is twice the percent by volume of alcohol present

Comment: As I understand it, the second meaning of "proof" comes from the British navy, where 100 Proof meant just enough concentration of alcohol to cause navy gunpowder to spontaneously combust, thus "proving" its potency. That strength was close to, and was later standardized to, 50 percent alcohol by volume.

Comment: @keshlam close, but not quite. Alcohol does _not_ make gunpowder spontaneously combust, that would have been quite a trick. What you're referring to is the practice of whetting the gunpowder with alcohol and testing whether it could then be lit. If so, the alcohol was strong enough. See, for example, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcohol_proof#History).

Comment: Ah. That does make more sense than the way I'd heard it. Correction appreciated! (It would be nice if the system didn't block editing of comments after 5 minutes... sigh.)

Comment: @keshlam please provide references for this type of claim. While _prove_ did indeed mean _test_ / _try_ I can find no evidence that that was the sense used in the idiom. What makes you say so? Wikipedia [traces it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_that_proves_the_rule#Original_meaning) to the Latin phrase _exceptio probat regulam in casibus non exceptis_ where _probat_ is translated as _confirms_. How would "the exception tests the rule" make sense?

Comment: @keshlam I looked into this a bit more and I see what you were getting at, that the exception tests whether the rule is true. That, however, is also [a misunderstanding](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/exception-that-proves-the-rule.html) of the phrase.

Comment: @keshlam I was delighted to find a sensible explanation for the maxim "the exception proves the rule", and upvoted your comment. Sadly, terdon's correction carries more authority. Can you please delete your comment, as I can't retract my incorrect endorsement.

Comment: Reluctantly. I disagree but am not willing to spend the time finding a counter-citation right now.

Comment: The important point from my deleted comment, for our current purposes, is that "prove" can also mean "test" (though this is a mostly archaic usage). We agree on that much, and it *could* eventually be a pitfall for someone learning the language -- though I grant that this may be more detail than is useful for the querant.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that would be the usual interpretation. Common example: "childproof" containers for medicines and other potentially dangerous things.

And those of us with cats are definitely familiar with the idea of trying to make things catproof; I need to keep the toilet paper covered when not in use or one of mine unrolls it.

Comment: And what needs to be apple-proof? A diabetic? I mean, I dunno, seriously. A window? Maybe an honest teacher?

Comment: A car windshield when parked under an apple tree? The fact that the term doesn't have a useful application doesn't make it meaningless, it just makes it useless.

Comment: Using Google Dictionary's first listed definition of _word_: **word** noun
1.
a single distinct **meaningful** element of speech or writing [bolding mine] and its 'synonym: term', together with M-W's **meaningful**: ' having an assigned function in a language system' encourages me to argue that a 'useless word' is a contradiction in terms. Chambers (20th C Dictionary) once famously 'defined' _mirbane_ as being 'an apparently meaningless word' but has since had the sense to drop that description.

Comment: Right. The compound word "appleproof" does have a clear meaning, even if it's not one that we'd often need.